# AngularJS: Pull To Refresh

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pull-to-refresh

I'm attempting to use mgcrea's Angular.js pull-to-refresh library, but I cannot get it to pull down and fire off. I can see the dotted line where it starts above the div, but it won't pull down at all. I'm not getting any errors in the Chrome Console or on Logcat.

**index.html**: Both the pull-to-refresh.js and css files are included here.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Mobile Dashboard</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no">

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600,700|Droid+Sans:400,700" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/mobile-angular-ui-base.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/fonts/icons.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/angular-pull-to-refresh.css" />

        <script src="assets/js/libs/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/libs/angular-route.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/libs/angular-touch.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/libs/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/libs/mobile-angular-ui.min.js"></script>

        <script src="assets/js/libs/angular-pull-to-refresh.js"></script>

        <script src="assets/js/app.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ontouchstart="" ng-app="mobile" class="blue">
        <div class="app">
            <div class="navbar navbar-app navbar-primary navbar-absolute-top">
                <div class="navbar-brand navbar-brand-left">
                    <div class="logo">
                        <img src="assets/img/logo_small.png" width="50px" height="50px" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="app-body">
                <ng-view class="app-content"></ng-view>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**miners.html**: I've tried placing pull-to-refresh in both the top div and the ul, but no dice.

```
<div class="scrollable">

      <ul id="miners" class="list-group list-group-table" pull-to-refresh="refresh()">
          <li ng-repeat="miner in miners" class="list-group-item">
              [foo code]
          </li>
          <li class="list-group-item">
            [more foo code]
          </li>
      </ul>

</div>
```

**Relevant css section**

```
.scrollable {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  overflow: auto;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: none;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: auto;
}
```

At this point, I'm completely and totally stuck. Does anyone have any ideas on what I might have missed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately I believe mgcrea's angular pull-to-refresh project has been abandoned.  Even the examples on his github readme no longer work, and there are several tickets indicating that other people are also not getting it to work.

Comment: I believe the same thing. We're investigating other options. Thanks!

Comment: Has anyone found anything else? I mean other than ionic. Ionic seems great, I'm just not ready to change everything (right this moment, that is...).

Comment: @Jason I built my own version into my app, and after seeing your comment I tried to extract it into a directive so other people could use it.  Right now it's heavily tied to angular-material because I'm using their progress bar, but if you're not using angular-material, you could adapt it to use your own indicator: Check out a demo of it [here](https://infomofo.github.io/angular-md-pull-to-refresh/app/). That demo will work on a mobile device or an emulated one.  The code is [here](https://github.com/infomofo/angular-md-pull-to-refresh). Please let me know if you have any feedback/suggestions!